# UITextField Uniqueness in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

In `UITableViewCell` there are multiple `uitextfield` in cell so how to identify which textfield generate action in `uitextfield` delegate method other than tag property?

Comment: Use the tag property.  Or compare addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your textfield is a member of a class? or created inside the method. If your textfield is a member variable you can check it by :

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ( [textfield isEqual:m_yourTextField] )
{

}
}
```

This way, you don't need to use tags. :D

Comment: almost good, but check if the pointers are the same, don't use the isEqual method: textfield == m_yourTextField.

Comment: Thanks, But if textfield is dynamically created and not member of class in such case what to do?

Comment: Hm.. You can assign it after you got the textfield on delegate method. For Example : - (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {  m_textFieldSelected = textField; } . And you can use m_textFieldSelected on your class. Also, what are you trying to do . So we can think other way to make it simple

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a tag value of particular textfield in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (like assign a indexPath.row) as a tag value and put the condition for it in `uitextfield` delegate method

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.yourtextField setTag:indexPath.row];

[cell.yourtextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textClicked:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then

```
-(void)textClicked:(UITextFiled*)txt
{
    NSLog(@"viewbuttonClicked:%ld",(long int)[txt tag]);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   if (textField == _txtPhone) {
     //Phone text field
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a bit more context? Without explainations, answers are not much worth.

Comment: Sure. If you just want to check the textfield and that is without tag than create a variable of textfield and directly compare it as show in above example.